# Ping from .launch file

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am attempting to add a line to my ros .launch file that would emulate the 'ping ##.#.###.##' command used in the command line. Is this possible? I am running Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295423/ping-from-.launch-file/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

'emulate' or actually run `ping`?

If the latter: see #q272267.

Running regular (ie: non-ROS) binaries from `roslaunch` is possible, but requires some special care.

The example there is with Python, but a simple bash script should also work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-03**:
With the assistance of your answer, I made a small python script and put that in the launch file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- For `ICMP` ping, you can also run [rosping](http://wiki.ros.org/rosping) node from your launch.
- For `xmlrpc` ping in ROS network level, in [rosnode](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnode) Python API there are some methods, e.g. [rosnode_ping](http://docs.ros.org/api/rosnode/html/rosnode-module.html#rosnode_ping). In the simplest form you can run a command like:

  ```
    python -c "import rosnode; rosnode.rosnode_ping('/rosout', verbose=True)"
  ```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-04**:
@AmateurHour: this is a good suggestion and was actually why I asked:

> 'emulate' or actually run `ping`?